# mysql AND index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an index structured as so:

```
BTREE merchant_id
BTREE flag

BTREE test    (merchant_id, flag)
```

I do a SELECT query as such :

```
 SELECT badge_id, merchant_id, badge_title, badge_class
FROM badges WHERE merchant_id = 1 AND flag = 1
```

what index would be better? Does it matter if they are in a seperate index?

Comment: Interesting question. Generally I would avoid adding the merchant_id-index as it is the left most part of the test-index. But if that is really faster for the select I don't know. However, adding more indexes adds a cost for all inserts so in total I think it's better to just add the two indexes. I tried to figure out how secondary indexes with multiple columns work but failed. I hope some one has the answer.

Comment: If all else fails, benchmark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer questions such as "Which column would be better to index?", and "Is the query planner using a certain index to execute the query?", you can use the [`EXPLAIN` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). See the excellent article [Analyzing Queries for Speed with `EXPLAIN`](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Analyzing-Queries-for-Speed-with-EXPLAIN/) for a comprehensive overview of the use of `EXPLAIN` in optimizing queries and schema.

In general, where a query can be optimized by indexing one of several columns, a helpful rule of thumb is to index the column that is "most unique" or "most selective" over all records; that is, index the column that has the most number of distinct values over all rows. I am guessing that in your case, the `merchant_id` column contains the most number of unique values, so it should probably be indexed. You can verify that an index choice is optimal using `EXPLAIN` on the query for all variations.

Note that the rule of thumb "index the most selective column" does not necessarily apply to the choice of the first column of a composite (also called compound or multi-column) index. It depends on your queries. If, for example, `employee_id` is the most selective column, but you need to execute queries like `SELECT * FROM badges WHERE flag = 17`, then having as the only index on table `badges` the composite index `(employee_id, flag)` would mean that the query results in a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Out of 3 indices you don't really need a separate merchant_id index, since merchant_id look-ups can use your "test" index.

More details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html